# Passing argument as const & or &&

Tags: c++, forward, rvalue

Consider the following, where some content is added to a vector through multiple layers:

```
class A {
public:
  void Add(Content c) {
    // Considerable amount of checking code here.
    v.push_back(c);
  }
private:
  std::vector<Content> v;
};

class B {
public:
  void Add(Content c) {
    // Considerable amount of additional code here.
    a.Add(c);
  }
private:
  A a;
};

class C {
public:
  void Add(Content c) {
    // Considerable amount of additional code here.
    b.Add(c);
  }
private:
  B b;
};
```

This can be continued but you see the point here. I want the content to be added either through copy or move, i.e. either via push_back(const Content&) or push_back(Content&&). The caller should be able to either call:

```
C c;
Content z;
c.Add(z);
```

or

```
c.Add(move(z));
```

and get a minimal number of copies.

Is there a way to achieve this without duplication of the additional code and without making the Add functions template functions?

Answer (score 2):

Overloading two methods for rvalue and lvalue is an approach:

```
void Add(const Content & c);
void Add(Content && c);
```

Using *perfect forwarding* you can avoid two overloads. You should make all `add` methods like this:

```
template<typename T>
void add(T&& a)
{
   b.Add(std::forward<T>(a));
}
```

Another approach which is better (IMO) is making `Content` movable. If `Content` is real class (not a placeholder for templates), you can do it:

```
class Content
{
public:
  Content(const Content &);
  Content(Content &&);

  Content &operator=(Content);  // Copy and swap idiom!

  ~Content();
};
```

After that you can re-write `Add` methods like below:

```
 void Add(Content c) {
    b.Add(std::move(c));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 }
```

The advantage of this approach is, you can transparent the moving or copying from caller side.

Comment: If I have n layers. Would I use call-by-value in all the Add methods? Or just in the outermost and the other would all be rvalue parameters? If first option: Can I be sure that all copies will be elided by the compiler?

Comment: The first solution would lead to code duplication, wouldn't it? The Add functions contain much more code than just the inner Add call.

Comment: @KitFisto: For the first solution, by perfect forwarding you can avoid code duplication. Why don't you make the `Content` movable to get rid of the duplication?

Comment: @KitFisto: (to your first comment). If you pick first solution, you should write `&&` overloads for all layers. If you pick second, you don't need them and passing by value is fine.

Comment: @M.M: I like the second solution but want to understand also the first one. How can I avoid to duplicate the checking code within Add function if I need two overloads? Perfect forwarding would require me to convert them into template functions wouldn't it?

Comment: @KitFisto: AFAIK, yes it needs two overloads. Or you can use perfect forwarding (universal references) which needs make it template (it's not really bad).

Answer (score 0):

You can add two methods with next signatures :

```
void Add(Content && c);
void Add(Content & c);
```

Other option is universal reference, but you need templates for that.